# ¿Cómo retornar la longitud del array de la respuesta de mi API en Angular?

Tags: angularjs-2.0

La función `size` **imprime** por la consola del navegador el número de elementos del JSON, pero quiero que `size` lo que haga sea devolver ese valor.

```
size()
{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4567/books')
               .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(result => {console.log(result.length)});
}
```

Ahora mismo lo que está haciendo es mostrarse por consola, pero quiero que la función **devuelva** el largo, y así utilizarlo en mi código.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "que lo haga sea devolver ese valor para poder utilizarlo posteriormente"?

Comment: Quiero que el result.length, que ahora mismo lo que está haciendo es mostrarse por consola, lo devuelva, para cuando yo llame a la función size, en vez de mostrarse por la consola del navegador, pueda utilizar su valor.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de suscribirte debes de volver a mapear/transformar el flujo de datos para que cuando se suscriban a el ya obtengan la cantidad de libros de tu API.

```
// Definición

size() {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:4567/books')
    .map(res => res.json()).map(res => res.length);
}

// Uso

size().subscribe(size => {
    console.log(size)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar el método `toPromise` del Observable:

```
size() {
  return this.http
    .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .map((array: any[])=> array.length)
    //.take(1)
    .toPromise()
}
```

Luego podrías usar la promesa que devuelve la función dentro de una función `async`:

```
async logSize() {
  const size = await this.size()
  console.log(size)
}
```

[**`EJEMPLO`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvgsix?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)